# What is a Lambda Group in serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, split-stacks

I'm looking into the `serverless-plugin-split-stacks` plugin of the serverless framework since I've hit the CloudFormation limit of 200 resources. In the [Migration Strategies](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-plugin-split-stacks#migration-strategies) section of its Github page, it says that I have three options:

- Per Lambda
- Per Type
- Per Lambda Group

The first two, I kinda get what they mean (but I'm not %100 sure). My question here is about the last option. What is a lambda group? And how can I group my lambda functions? Is it something done manually or they are grouped automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look into the plugin code [per-group-function.js](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-plugin-split-stacks/blob/master/lib/migration-strategy/per-group-function.js)

The plugin auto-group based on the `nestedStackCount` option.

So, as an example, the following `serverless.yml`:

```yaml
custom:
  splitStacks:
    perFunction: false
    perType: false
    perGroupFunction: true
    nestedStackCount: 10
```

Will group into 10 stacks as:

```
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - 10NestedStack: 4
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - 1NestedStack: 3
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - 2NestedStack: 1
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - 3NestedStack: 3
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - 4NestedStack: 8
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - 5NestedStack: 5
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - 6NestedStack: 5
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - 7NestedStack: 3
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - 8NestedStack: 4
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - 9NestedStack: 4
```

Based on the condition on the script, you need to set `nestedStackCount` equals or greater than 3.